# Can slack webhooks mention multiple users in a single webhook request?

Tags: webhooks, slack

As title says, I'm looking to send a single request to a web-hook to mention multiple users. At the moment, from testing I can only seem to get it to mention one and any more results in it either converting the entire body to a string or simply mentioning one.

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
  --data '{"incoming":"user@email.com"}' \
  https://hooks.slack.com/workflows/ID
```

This is the call I'm making to the workflow Webhook URL & I was trying to use the user's email as an indetifier. It works for the first but not for any others.

Any info is greatly appreciated, I *know* I'm doing something dumb here!

Comment: Have you considered [creating a user group](https://slack.com/help/articles/212906697-Create-a-user-group) and just mentioning the group? This would also make it more flexible

Comment: Usergroups would be good but I'm not sure if I can programmatically create these with just workflow access. At the moment we can only use workflows and the list of users would change dynamically

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this myself the bad way.

I simply added additional values that I can fill in as needed. It's messy, but however I believe the best way to do this based on the limited permissions and the available functionality of Workflows.